# Is there a REST API call for Azure Mobile Service's Scheduler Run Once?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-mobile-services

Using the Azure portal, I can click the Run Once button on a Scheduler job to execute it. Is that functionality available via a REST call from my app? The scenario is that periodically a job is run to check for changes in data. The first time the app starts up, I would like to execute that job once as not to have to wait for the scheduled time.

What is the call to kick off a scheduled job? Would I have to duplicate code in both the scheduler job and custom API and then call the custom API from my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a scheduler job by sending a `POST` request to `/jobs/<jobName>` (no request body required). But you need to pass the master key of your mobile service (in the `x-zumo-master` HTTP header), so you should only do that from a location that is not visible to your users - you don't want anyone getting a hold of your master key, as this would open up your service for all kinds of attacks.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom API call that then did a POST to kick off the job.  Guess it would work just as well to put the code for the job in the custom API and have the scheduled job call the API endpoint.