# How to call a Azure Mobile Service Scheduled Job in the same manner as the Run Once button in the portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

Trying to use this question and answer but it does not address the issue I'm having. [Is there a REST API call for Azure Mobile Service's Scheduler Run Once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861700/is-there-a-rest-api-call-for-azure-mobile-services-scheduler-run-once)

I have a Azure Mobile Service which has a Job that I want to call from an Azure Scheduler job.

So what I have done so far is use the Azure Scheduler API and create a job within a job collection to run at a specific time of the day. This job is then meant to call a job within the Azure Mobile Service.

The code to create a job in the Azure Scheduler is below

```
var result = schedulerClient.Jobs.CreateOrUpdate("Job Name", new JobCreateOrUpdateParameters()
            {
                Action = new JobAction()
                {
                    Type = JobActionType.Https,
                    Request = new JobHttpRequest()
                    {
                        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {
                            { "x-zumo-application", "Mobile Service Password" }
                        },
                        Method = "POST",
                        Uri = new Uri("https://[mobile service host].net/jobs/[job Name]")
                    }
                },
                StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow, // This can be any time of the day, just set here for the example
                Recurrence = new JobRecurrence()
                {
                    Frequency = JobRecurrenceFrequency.Day,
                    Interval = 1,
                    Count = 1
                }
            });
```

For the header in the above snippet I have used "Authorisation" and "x-zumo-master" neither of which works as I get the following error below.

```
Http Action - Response from host '[mobile service host]': 'Unauthorized' Response Headers: Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 08:57:42 GMT
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=..............;Path=/;Domain=[mobile service host]
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Service"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Body: {"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Can anyone help with resolving the above error? As mentioned before I've tried a couple of different header values but its still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this...

http://blog.gluwer.com/2013/07/azure-mobile-services-jobs-on-demand/

You need to use both x-zumo-application and x-zumo-master

These keys can be found on the Azure Management Portal, where a button will appear at the bottom when you go onto your Mobile Service Dashboard.